# How do you set to nil/modify embedded data in mongoid in the Rails console?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mongodb, mongoid

Currently I have a `User` table that has a `toys_owned` column that is an embedded document.  How do I set to nil/modify the embedded document in my rails console? Currently it is giving me a `NoMethodError` when I try to set it to `nil`.

Note: I'm trying to avoid using the mongo shell if possible

app/models/toysOwned.rb

```
class ToysOwned
  include Mongoid::Document

  embedded_in :user, :inverse_of => :toys_owned
  referenced_in :toy
end
```

Rails Console:

```
User.where(email: "john1433@aol.com").first.toys_owned
 => [#<ToysOwned _id: 7e5s72d19gb23f0001203025, toy_id: BSON::ObjectId('6g46af0g2ffchc000100003d')>]
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :049 > u = User.where(email: "john1433@aol.com").first.toys_owned.first
 => #<ToysOwned _id: 7e5s72d19gb23f0001203025, toy_id: BSON::ObjectId('6g46af0g2ffchc000100003d')>
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :051 > u = nil
 => nil 
ruby-1.9.2-p290 :052 > u.save
NoMethodError: undefined method `save' for nil:NilClass
```

app/models/user.rb (some of it)

```
class User
  include Mongoid::Document
  include Mongoid::Timestamps

  include ToyOwnable
  ...520 lines of code...
end
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this, it should work:

```
user = User.where(email: "john1433@aol.com").first
user.toys_owned.shift
user.save
```

If you read your code for a couple of minutes, you'll realize that you're doing crazy things :)

First, you set `u` to a first of `toys_owned`. Then you set this reference `u` to `nil`. This **does not** affect original `toys_owned` collection. Then you're trying to call a method on `u` (which is `nil` at the moment and can't fulfill your request).

Comment: Using the second query produces the following error:
`NoMethodError: undefined method 'first' for #<ToysOwned:0x00000103a13ef8>`.  Then I tried `u.toys_owned.first = (u.toys_owned.first || []).shift` and its giving me a `NoMethodError: undefined method 'shift' for #<ToysOwned:0x00000103a13ef8>` error

Comment: Yep, I ran it exactly as is.  Made sure to double check. I've added just a very small portion of the User.rb because there is just too much code. Is there something specific you are looking for?

Comment: What's the type of `user.toys_owned`? Is it a collection or single element?

Comment: Its an embedded document so I'm assuming it is a collection

Comment: In case if document isn't removed on save, [read this one](http://spin.atomicobject.com/2011/04/13/mongoid-hash-field-types-watch-out/).

Comment: It looks like the items are being removed but it is not saving.  I am looking at that document. Does that mean I need to put the deep_copy function in my users.rb file or should I put it in a common utility file?

Comment: @Goalie: try the simplest thing possible.